# Display specified variations of a configurable product in category display page, all linking to configurable PDP

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.3.1, magento-2-commerce

This is less of a coding question and more of community knowledge. We would like to include product filters on our site, specifically for size and width. However, at the moment, for products with multiple attributes, such as colour, size, and width, we choose one variation from each colour to be displayed in catalog view, and disable the parent configurable from being displayed at all. This ensures that customers are exposed to all colours of a configurable in the catalog view, while they all are linked to the configurable PDP.

We would like to implement size and width filters, however this is impossible with the current configuration as the filters would use the information from the individual simple products we have enabled for catalog view, so if we had enabled the width:medium size:5 for all colours of a configurable, if you were to filter by width:wide, then nothing would show.

Is anyone aware of any custom modifications to Magento 2.3 commerce back-end, or any modules that have implemented a work around for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!